# Good Pivot Table / Data Table algorithm in Java

Tags: java, database, algorithm, pivot, pivot-table

I have a database to access via JDBC which returns around 200k of records I have to consolidate data table style for further processing. I could if that leads to good performance send a few SELECT (Count(...) ...) statements upfront.

What is a good algorithm in Java to compute such a pivot table?

**Clarification** 
I specifically look for a Java solution, not a SQL approach (and the back end isn't Oracle)

Comment: Generally databases are much better suited to manipulating large volumes of data than Java.  Why not do the pivoting in SQL and just grab the end product through JDBC?

Comment: it may help a lot if you transform the question to "How to do X in SQL?" instead of "How to do X in Java?". You're underestimating the DB powers.

Comment: While I access the data via JDBC, it isn't a SQL database. And actually I know how to do that in SQL